# Is there a way to get webpack to fail-fast? Lerna as well

Tags: webpack-4, lerna

I have a lerna bootstrap webpack 4 monorepo I'm trying to upgrade however I can. When trying to migrate to workspaces I'll often get failures in like 10 packages/workspaces and each one will have like 1000 lines after the first error from webpack.

Is there any way to get webpack to fail-fast and only report the 1st error?
Same thing with lerna, anyway to fail-fast and only report the first failed workspace?